# How to get the value from a @JoinColumn using Spring batch and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-batch

### Introduction

In order to extract some data from a database, I am trying to setup a basic hibernate and spring batch project. The goal is to provide one query (HQL) and based on this query the spring batch application extracts all the data to a flat file.

One of the requirements of the application is that the user should not have to configure the mappings of the columns. As such I am trying to create a DynamicRecordProcessor that evaluates the input and passes the input (a table for example Address) to the writer in such a way that the flat file item writer can use a PassThroughFieldExtractor.

Below the reader-processor-writer xml configuration:

```
<!-- Standard Spring Hibernate Reader -->
<bean id="hibernateItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateCursorItemReader">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />         
    <property name="queryString" value="from Address" />                
</bean> 

<!-- Custom Processor -->
<bean id="dynamicRecordProcessor" class="nl.sander.mieras.processor.DynamicRecordProcessor"/>   

<!-- Standard Spring Writer -->
<bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:target/extract/output.txt" />  
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter" value="|"/>
            <property name="fieldExtractor">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughFieldExtractor"/>                                   
            </property>             
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**EDIT:**
And the job configuration:

```
<bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>           
    <property name="cacheableMappingLocations" value="classpath*:META-INF/mappings/*.hbm.xml"/>    
</bean> 

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

### Problem

My processor looks as following:

```
public class DynamicRecordProcessor<Input,Output> implements ItemProcessor<Input,Output> {  

    private static final String DELIMITER = "|";
    private boolean areNamesSetup = false;

    private List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Input item;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Output process(Input item) throws Exception {
        this.item = item;       
        initMapping();              
        return (Output) extract();      
    }

    private void initMapping() {
        if (!areNamesSetup) {
            mapColumns();
        }
        areNamesSetup = true;
    }

    private void mapColumns() {     
        Field[] allFields = item.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : allFields) {
            if (!field.getType().equals(Set.class) && Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())) {               
                names.add(field.getName());                 
            }
        }
    }   

    private Object extract() {
        List<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();
        BeanWrapper bw = new BeanWrapperImpl(item);     
        for (String propertyName : this.names) {                        
            values.add(bw.getPropertyValue(propertyName));          
        }       
        return StringUtils.collectionToDelimitedString(values, DELIMITER);      
    }   
}
```

The table Address has the following field:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="city_id", nullable=false)
    public City getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }
```

And the corresponding column in city:

```
@Column(name="city_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Short getCityId() {
        return this.cityId;
    }
```

When using `values.add(bw.getPropertyValue(propertyName));` with propertyName being "city" the following exception occurs:

```
org.hibernate.SessionException: proxies cannot be fetched by a stateless session
    at org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.immediateLoad(StatelessSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:68)
    at nl.sander.mieras.localhost.sakila.City_$$_jvstc2c_d.toString(City_$$_jvstc2c_d.java)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2982)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at org.springframework.util.StringUtils.collectionToDelimitedString(StringUtils.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.util.StringUtils.collectionToDelimitedString(StringUtils.java:1148)
    at nl.sander.mieras.processor.DynamicRecordProcessor.extract(DynamicRecordProcessor.java:52)
    at nl.sander.mieras.processor.DynamicRecordProcessor.process(DynamicRecordProcessor.java:27)
```

The value, however, is availabe as shown in the screenshot below.
[image]

***Concrete question: How can I get the value 300?***

I have tried getting the value using reflection API, but I couldn't reach the actual value I want to get...

### Reproduce

I have setup a public repo. However, you still need a local database to be able to reproduce exactly the issue. https://github.com/Weirdfishees/hibernate-batch-example. Any suggestions how isolate this issue further are more then welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flip your reader to be state-full instead of stateless with the `useStatelessSession` property:

```
<!-- Standard Spring Hibernate Reader -->
<bean id="hibernateItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateCursorItemReader">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />         
    <property name="queryString" value="from Address" />
    <property name="useStatelessSession" value="false" />       
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dean. Your solution creates another error unfortunately.

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.close()Ljava/sql/Connection;
 at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemReaderHelper.close(HibernateItemReaderHelper.java:200)
 at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateCursorItemReader.doClose(HibernateCursorItemReader.java:229)`

Comment: That indicates a possibly dependency version mismatch between Spring and Hibernate. Try knocking the Hibernate version down to `4.3.11.Final`

Comment: Very nice, thank you! Now in my output file the actual object gets printed (nl.sander.mieras.localhost.sakila.City@707865bd), which is an improvement from not printing anything at all. A little bit outside the scope of this question, but I will ask anyway; do you have any idea how to get the actual value from the object (being a short value of 300) ?

Comment: Override the default `toString()` method in your `City` class